# when using using docker-compose, how to post a post request to another container in BlazorWASM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, uri, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm as a frontend and a GraphQL as a backend solution.
both services are dockerised without problem, they are independently functional.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml`,

```yaml
version: "3.4"
name: search_and_map

services:
  blazor_wasm:
    image: fdq09eca/search_and_map-blazor_wasm
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/NDSH.Geospatial.Demos.SearchAndMap.Blazor/src/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  graphql_api:
    image: fdq09eca/search_and_map-graphql_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/NDSH.Geospatial.Demos.SearchAndMap.Api/src/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 51803:80
```

I try to post a post request to the backend in `BlazorWASM` as the following.

```cs
private async void GetAllBgsLayersFromGraphqlApi(MetadataSearchModel metadataSearchModel) {
        
        Uri graphqlApiUri = new Uri("http://search_and_map-graphql_api-1:80/graphql/");
      try {
        
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var queryContent = @"
query { 
  bgsLayers { 
    recordId,
    fileIdentifier,
    relatedDataSetUuId,
    operatesOnTitle,
    wmsLayerName,
    wmsLayerTitle,
    wmsLayerAbstract,
    wmsGetCapabilityUrl,
    arcGisMapServerUrl,
    arcGisLayerUrl,
    arcGisLayerName
  } 
}";
        var queryObject = new { query = queryContent };
        var queryJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryObject);
        
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage {
          RequestUri = graphqlApiUri,
          Method = HttpMethod.Post,
          Content = new StringContent(content: queryJson, encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, mediaType: "application/json"),
        };
        

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request)) {
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<BgsLayer>>>>(responseString);
          metadataSearchModel.BgsLayers = obj!["data"]["bgsLayers"];
          return;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("calling GraphQL API ERROR!!");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"[ERR] {ex.Message}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"[uri] {graphqlApiUri.AbsolutePath}");

        throw;
      }
    }
```

the `graphqlApiUri` has not been resolved correctly, in the browser it shows the following

[image: browser result]

If I use `http://localhost:51803/graphql` it works fine locally, but when I `docker compose up` on an ec2 instance, it is problematic.

How can I resolve the URI correctly and work on local and hosted ec2?

Thank you.

Comment: The troubleshooting for this error should be the same as for any other DNS error where the URL does not resolve to a valid IP address, and it doesn't require your program to fix.

Comment: i got into both container and using their name to ping each other, it all works fine. i also check the `docker network inspect` and i still cannot find anything wrong.